# Cursor from db.rawQuery SELECT SUM returns null: how to catch?

Tags: android, mysql

I'm running the following query,

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(surveycount) FROM surveyDB WHERE species = " + "'" + szSpecies + "' AND location = " + "'" + szLocation + "'", null);
```

With the database column "surveycount" declared as an INT when the table is created. The below code works fine except when no records are returned that have the target string values for szSpecies and szLocation at which point szSum is shown as null.

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            szSum = c.getString(0);
            c.close();}
            else{
                //do nothing
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"It was NULL",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Surveycount SUM = "+szSum+" .",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

How can I catch this errant cursor output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, changing out this,

```
szSum = c.getString(0);
```

for this

```
iSum=c.getInt(0);
```

appears to have solved the problem with zero being returned when querying  location or species qualifier combinations that lack common counts.
Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

First check if the cursor is not null and then see if the cursor.getcount() is greater than 0, only then try to retrieve values from cursor.

Updated code as below:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(surveycount) FROM surveyDB WHERE species = " + "'" + szSpecies + "' AND location = " + "'" + szLocation + "'", null); 
  szSum="";

if(c!=null && c.getCount()>0)
{
            c.moveToFirst()
            szSum = c.getString(0);
            c.close();
} else{
   //do nothing
   Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"It was NULL",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

if(!szSum.equals(""))
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Surveycount SUM = "+szSum+" .",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

`getCount ()`: Returns the numbers of rows in the cursor

Comment: getCount() returns "1" both when a value is returned and when szSum shows "null".

Comment: @portsample Use DatabaseUItils.dumpCursor

Comment: @portsample There were some problems in my code, just corrected those. Did not understand your comment, can you elaborate.

Comment: getCount() returns "1" both when an actual sum is returned of rows where szSpecies and szLocation match the query values, as well as when there is "no match"...this state produces a "null" string when szSum = c.getString(0)...also I've put getCount directly after the rawquery as well as after "if(c!=null && c.getCount()>0){" with the same results.  Thanks.

Comment: @pskink dumpcursor = ...{Sum(surveycount)=null}

Comment: Use "?" and second param of rawQuery, does it change anything?

Comment: @pskink Please clarify. Thanks.